# How to make Spotlight ONLY index certain file types?

Tags: spotlight

I use my mac for development, and create/delete so many (big) files that I ended up turning Spotlight off, since it was taking so much time indexing these files.

I think it would be fine if I would only allow Spotlight to index pdf and doc documents, is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

As there is no easy way (no GUI certainly) to exclude file types, your best bet might be to exclude specific directories from being indexed. Create/delete Your big files inside one directory (including subdirs) and go to *Preferences -> Spotlight -> Privacy* and choose Your excluded directory (You can also drag and drop it).

Comment: thanks @mateusz-szlosek, but that won't cut it: I create thousands of files on a daily basis (as a dev), and they are in many different places...

Comment: @Renaud Maybe you should organize your project(s) under a/some specific folder(s).